# mini_racer gem not able to install on Github Actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github-actions

I came to work on Monday morning (9th Oct 2023) and suddenly for no good reason my project's Github Actions CI stop working due to `mini_racer` gem not able to install

It worked on Friday (6th Oct. 2023, no one pushed any change)

did Github changed something?

full log

```
Installing dartsass-rails 0.3.0
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
/home/runner/work/myproject/myproject/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/mini_racer-0.6.3/ext/mini_racer_extension
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.0.3/x64/bin/ruby -I
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.0.3/x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0 -r
./siteconf20231009-2476-stlahy.rb extconf.rb
checking for -lpthread... yes
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
  --with-opt-dir
  --without-opt-dir
  --with-opt-include
  --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
  --with-opt-lib
  --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
  --with-make-prog
  --without-make-prog
  --srcdir=.
  --curdir
  --ruby=/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.0.3/x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
  --with-pthread-dir
  --without-pthread-dir
  --with-pthread-include
  --without-pthread-include=${pthread-dir}/include
  --with-pthread-lib
  --without-pthread-lib=${pthread-dir}/lib
  --with-pthreadlib
  --without-pthreadlib
  --enable-debug
  --disable-debug
  --enable-asan
  --disable-asan
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.0.3/x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/psych.rb:457:in
`parse_stream': undefined method `parse' for #<Psych::Parser:0x0000563746cb82d8
@handler=#<Psych::Handlers::DocumentStream:0x0000563746cb83f0 @stack=[],
@last=nil, @root=nil, @start_line=nil, @start_column=nil, @end_line=nil,
@end_column=nil, @block=#<Proc:0x0000563746cb8328
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.0.3/x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/psych.rb:391>>,
@external_encoding=0> (NoMethodError)
  from /opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.0.3/x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/psych.rb:391:in `parse'
from /opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.0.3/x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/psych.rb:280:in
`unsafe_load'
from
/home/runner/work/myproject/myproject/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/libv8-node-16.10.0.0-x86_64-linux/ext/libv8-node/location.rb:21:in
`block in load!'
from
/home/runner/work/myproject/myproject/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/libv8-node-16.10.0.0-x86_64-linux/ext/libv8-node/location.rb:20:in
`open'
from
/home/runner/work/myproject/myproject/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/libv8-node-16.10.0.0-x86_64-linux/ext/libv8-node/location.rb:20:in
`load!'
from
/home/runner/work/myproject/myproject/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/libv8-node-16.10.0.0-x86_64-linux/lib/libv8/node.rb:8:in
`configure_makefile'
  from extconf.rb:77:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
be found here:

/home/runner/work/myproject/myproject/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/3.0.0/mini_racer-0.6.3/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
/home/runner/work/myproject/myproject/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/mini_racer-0.6.3
for inspection.
Results logged to
/home/runner/work/myproject/myproject/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/3.0.0/mini_racer-0.6.3/gem_make.out

/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.0.3/x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:93:in
`run'
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.0.3/x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:47:in
`block in build'
  /opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.0.3/x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tempfile.rb:317:in `open'
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.0.3/x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:26:in
`build'
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.0.3/x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:159:in
`build_extension'
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.0.3/x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:193:in
`block in build_extensions'
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.0.3/x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:190:in
`each'
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.0.3/x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:190:in
`build_extensions'
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.0.3/x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/installer.rb:845:in
`build_extensions'
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.0.3/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:72:in
`build_extensions'
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.0.3/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:28:in
`install'
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.0.3/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:202:in
`install'
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.0.3/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:54:in
`install'
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.0.3/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:16:in
`install_from_spec'
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.0.3/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:156:in
`do_install'
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.0.3/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:147:in
`block in worker_pool'
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.0.3/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/worker.rb:62:in
`apply_func'
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.0.3/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/worker.rb:57:in
`block in process_queue'
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.0.3/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in
`loop'
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.0.3/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in
`process_queue'
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.0.3/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/worker.rb:90:in
`block (2 levels) in create_threads'

An error occurred while installing mini_racer (0.6.3), and Bundler cannot
continue.

In Gemfile:
  mini_racer
Error: The process '/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.0.3/x64/bin/bundle' failed with exit code 5
```

Comment: Do you really need/want mini_racer? The modern approach is to use Node to install JS runtimes.

Comment: good point, I removed mini_racer and it all worked 

Comment: what do you use instead?

Answer (score 0):

Ok as @max mentioned in the question comment `mini_racer` gem is not needed at all in the CI as we are referencing node environment in Github Actions

So we removed `mini_racer` from Gemfile and it all worked

now if you need it for any reason in dev (or prod) you can

```
group :development do
  gem "mini_racer"
end
```